# QuickBlox Opponent Video and audio call is not coming in Android When App in background and App completely destroy From Memory

Tags: android, quickblox-android

I am using QuickBlox SDk for video calling. When i call from one user to another,
When My App in background but if My app comes in foreground then Video and Audio 
call coming . Can you please suggest me how can i resolve this problem. Even when I am trying Quickblox's demo app, then also I am getting same issue.
  Please help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using Services  to recieve incoming video call and audio call request and then Notifications to notify users of incoming request and give them the choice to respond or reject.

Comment: Hi  theSereneRebel
  Can you send me a demo service code if you have implemented before.